# Calling a father Abba, when his name is Abba

Tags: halacha, names, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

May a child call his father Abba - if his name is Abba?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Kibbud Av VaEim UMoraam 6:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52003&st=&pgnum=52) cites two opinions on this subject. Chida and Sdei Chemed argue that indeed in that case the child should use a different title for his father; by contrast, the Ben Ish Chai (in his responsa Torah Lishmah) says that "Abba" is inherently a respectful title.

(It is interesting, too, that we find the amora Shmuel calling his father "Abba" when that was his personal name - [Berachos 18b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=18b&format=pdf).)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abba_bar_Abba